# Do we need to specify python interpreter externally if python script contains #!/usr/bin/python3?

Tags: python, c, system, interpreter

I am trying to invoke python script from C application using `system()` call

The python script has `#!/usr/bin/python3` on the first line.

If I do `system(python_script)`, the script does not seem to run.

It seems I need to do `system(/usr/bin/python3 python_script)`.

I thought I do not need to specify the interpreter externally if I have `#!/usr/bin/python3` in the first line of the script.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the script have the executable bit set? (`chmod +x python_script`)

Comment: Does `python_script`, which appears to be a filename, contain a `/` anywhere? If not, the directory containing it must be in your shell's search path.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Sorry, but that is wrong.

Comment: `system(3)` invokes the shell which will have a $PATH

Comment: @L3viathan Thank you!

Comment: @Olaf Is my interpretation of the behavior documented in  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01_01 , Command Search and Execution, incorrect?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: It ignores the potential for having `./` in `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have executable permission for `python_script`.
You can make `python_script` executable by

`chmod +x python_script`

Also check if you are giving correct path for `python_script`